# Pass multiple arguments to anonymous function w/ call_user_func

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I have an array of arguments that I want to pass to a function via `call_user_func`. The following code will currently give the error: `Missing argument 2 for Closure`. How can this be rewritten to work properly?

```
$args = array('foo', 'bar');
call_user_func(function($arg1, $arg2) {}, $args);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) if you're looking to pass an array of parameters.

Comment: @KyleDecot The best way to thank me is by accepting an answer if this worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Know this has been answered. However the following also works fine.

Exec between 100,000 accesses

---

1.006599 : call_user_func($func, $value)

1.193323 : call_user_func((array($object, $func), $value)

1.232891 : call_user_func_array($func, array($value))

1.309725 : call_user_func_array((array($object, $func), array($value)

If you need to use **call_user_func** :

```
call_user_func(
    $function,
        $arg1,$arg2
);
```

If you need to use **call_user_func_array** :

```
call_user_func_array(
    $function,
        array($arg1,$arg2)
);
```

By design both can pass in arrays regardless. However, also by design one may be more required for use, than the other. It all depends on what it is being used for. A simplistic array set passes just fine and faster, in call_user_func.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass them one by one, or have the callback function accept an array as an argument and do the parsing internally.